# Render And Download PDF Rendered by Phantomjs

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, screenshot, tornado, casperjs

I have used phantomjs for pdf and png screenshot capture. Everything works pretty well but i am facing a situation where the outputs are saved into a directory. Now how can i enable download functionalities so that as soon as print button is clicked the rendering happens and download the file in client side immediately using phantomjs.

Answer (score 0):

I got a suggestion from one of my friend and a good programmer who has worked in phantomjs for pdf print. The suggestion was after render the file redirect to a url which maps in downloading the given filename.